# Find a node using XPath based on it's contents

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xpath

I have an XML file that has at various depths snippets such as this:

```
<NativeDicomModel>
  <DicomAttribute tag="0040A730" vr="SQ" keyword="ContentSequence">
    <Item number="100">
      <DicomAttribute tag="0040A010" vr="CS" keyword="RelationshipType">
        <Value number="1">CONTAINS</Value>
      </DicomAttribute>
      <DicomAttribute tag="0040A040" vr="CS" keyword="ValueType">
        <Value number="1">NUM</Value>
      </DicomAttribute>
      <DicomAttribute tag="0040A043" vr="SQ" keyword="ConceptNameCodeSequence">
        <Item number="1">
          <DicomAttribute tag="00080100" vr="SH" keyword="CodeValue">
            <Value number="1">29436-3</Value>
          </DicomAttribute>
          <DicomAttribute tag="00080102" vr="SH" keyword="CodingSchemeDesignator">
            <Value number="1">LN</Value>
          </DicomAttribute>
          <DicomAttribute tag="00080104" vr="LO" keyword="CodeMeaning">
            <Value number="1">Left Ventricle Internal End Diastolic Dimension</Value>
          </DicomAttribute>
        </Item>
      </DicomAttribute>  
    </Item>
  </DicomAttribute>
</NativeDicomModel>
```

I am wanting to get all `Item` nodes where the `CodeMeaning` is a specific value. So for the above snippet I would search for `Item` where `CodeMeaning` is equal to "Left Ventricle Internal End Diastolic Dimension".

I am not super versed in XPath but I have tried a few variations of the following to no success:

`string xpath = "//item[@keyword='ConceptNameCodeSequence']/DicomAttribute[@keyword='CodeMeaning' and text()='Left Ventricle Internal End Diastolic Dimension']"`

Is there a clean way to do this, or any alternate methods?

Comment: Please edit your question and provide real XML starting with its root element plus your real code. So it will be a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve it fairly quickly by changing my thought process by working bottom up. I came upon the following expression:

`string xpath = "//*[Value='Left Ventricle Internal End Diastolic Dimension']/ancestor::Item";`

This returns me the `Item` node as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following XPath expression.

**XPath**

```
/NativeDicomModel/DicomAttribute//Item[DicomAttribute/@keyword="CodeMeaning" and DicomAttribute/Value="Left Ventricle Internal End Diastolic Dimension"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a tree structure so to get the hierarchy use following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            XElement xDicomAttribute = doc.Descendants("DicomAttribute").FirstOrDefault();

            DicomAttribute root = new DicomAttribute(xDicomAttribute);

            List<DicomAttribute> nodes = DicomAttribute.FindNode(root, "CodeMeaning", "Left Ventricle Internal End Diastolic Dimension");

        }
    }
    public class DicomAttribute
    {
        public string tag { get; set; }
        public string vr { get; set; }
        public string keyword { get; set; }

        public string text { get; set; }
        public int? number { get; set; }

        public Item item { get; set; }

        public DicomAttribute(XElement xDicomAttribute)
        {
            tag = (string)xDicomAttribute.Attribute("tag");
            vr = (string)xDicomAttribute.Attribute("vr");
            keyword = (string)xDicomAttribute.Attribute("keyword");

            XElement xValue = xDicomAttribute.Element("Value");
            if (xValue != null)
            {
                text = (string)xValue;
                number = (int?)xValue.Attribute("number");
            }

            XElement xItem = xDicomAttribute.Element("Item");
            if (xItem != null)
            {
                item = new Item(xItem);
            }
        }
        public static List<DicomAttribute> FindNode(DicomAttribute dicomAttribute, string keyword, string text)
        {
            List<DicomAttribute> dicomAttributes = null;
            if (dicomAttribute.keyword == keyword && dicomAttribute.text == text)
            {
                dicomAttributes = new List<DicomAttribute>();
                dicomAttributes.Add(dicomAttribute);
            }
            if (dicomAttribute.item != null)
            {
                foreach (DicomAttribute child in dicomAttribute.item.dicomAttributes)
                {
                    List<DicomAttribute> childDicomAttributes = FindNode(child, keyword, text);
                    if (childDicomAttributes != null)
                    {
                        if (dicomAttributes == null)
                        {
                            dicomAttributes = childDicomAttributes;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            dicomAttributes.AddRange(childDicomAttributes);
                        }
                    }

                }
            }


            return dicomAttributes;

        }
    }
    public class Item
    {
        public int number { get; set; }
        public List<DicomAttribute> dicomAttributes { get; set;}

        public Item(XElement xItem)
        {
            number = (int)xItem.Attribute("number");
            foreach (XElement dicomAttribute in xItem.Elements("DicomAttribute"))
            {
                DicomAttribute newDicomAttribute = new DicomAttribute(dicomAttribute);
                if (dicomAttributes == null) dicomAttributes = new List<DicomAttribute>();
                dicomAttributes.Add(newDicomAttribute);
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get first parent "Item" nodes from "Value" nodes, you need to use that xpath:

```
string xpath = @"//*[Value='Left Ventricle Internal End Diastolic Dimension']/parent::Item";
```

or

```
string xpath = @"//*[//@keyword='CodeMeaning']/*[Value='Left Ventricle Internal End Diastolic Dimension']/parent::Item";
```

So, if you need to get "Item" from root xml, follow that [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65784352/12830409)

Example, where xml.xml is your XML file

```
using System.Xml;

namespace XPathFind
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
            xml.Load("xml.xml");
            XmlNodeList nodeList = xml.SelectNodes(@"//*[//@keyword='CodeMeaning']/*[Value='Left Ventricle Internal End Diastolic Dimension']/parent::Item");
        }
    }
}
```